# srcset doesn't work on iPhone

Tags: iphone, resolution, srcset

I'm using srcset on my project, everything goes well till I test on iPhone, then srcset sudenly don't work, here my code:

```
 <picture class="banner-hero__picture-container">
   <source srcset="../../../../../xxx/01-480.jpg" media="(max-width: 479px)">
   <source srcset="../../../../../xxx/01-768.jpg" media="(max-width: 767px)">
   <source srcset="../../../../../xxx/01-1200.jpg" media="(max-width: 1199px)">
   <img src="../../../../../xxx/01-1920.jpg" class="banner-hero__image">
 </picture>
```

I know there are sone rules about pixel density, but on iPhone in portait (320px, avec retina 640px) the image loaded is the 1920px, not even the 768px.

*(tested on iPhone 5)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`picture` is not supported yet in WebKit. Use picturefill.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture
http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/